# About layer.shadow on iOS development

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

if I use layer.shadow like this:

```
self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1.5);
self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
```

and put some(not more than 10) of these views(without images) into a `UIScrollView`,
it makes the `scrollView` very slow when is scrolling.

if I remove any codes about shadow, scrolling become quite smooth again.

FYI, the un-smooth case happen when running the app on iOS device,
but smooth on iOS simulator.

Does any one know how to keep both shadow and smooth scrolling?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will help if you set a shadow path and set the should rasterize flag on the layer.

Something like this:

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds];
self.layer.shadowPath = [path CGPath];
self.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

Comment: i just add: self.layer.shouldRasterize = YES. and everything is smooth! thx. but what is "shouldRasterize" actually do?

Comment: shouldRasterize renders the layer as a bitmap.  Here's the docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004500-CH1-SW44